# Austrian LoCo team Ask Ubuntu integration idea

Tags: discussion, loco

I'd like to have our LoCo team (Austrian LoCo) fully integrated into Ask Ubuntu.

Now the question or idea I had is, what would be the policy on questions written in German and translated into English by our LoCo and possibly other german speaking Ask Ubuntu members (only if they want to help with that)?

The idea is to allow people, that don't speak English that well or that don't feel that comfortable to write English, to use Ask Ubuntu as their tech support channel.

An example. Peter has a problem with setting up an account in Gwibber and posts the initial question on German. A member of our LoCo would then post a translated version below. Answers would be provided solely in English.

What do you think about that?

Comment: I'm doubtful the translations would be 'perfect', though I'd love for you to prove me wrong. However, if all the questions have to be manually checked for correctness, well... that doesn't really scale does it? The same goes for translating the English answers back to German.

Answer (score 4):

I would be very careful with this.

Perhaps try it once or twice as a test, to see how it works, and to see what the community thinks of it, before moving forward?